# Click webform button from bash

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to "click" a button on a webpage from a bash script. I was told to try using curl but I've not been able to figure it out. I don't need to fill out any input info, just simulate navigating to a page and clicking a button (login is also necessary).

Here is the output of formfind:

```
server:$ ~/formfind < ./site.html 
--- FORM report. Uses GET to URL "/view/job/26/search/"
Input: NAME="q" VALUE="search" (TEXT)
--- end of FORM
--- FORM report. Uses POST to URL "Job/pass"
Button: "Execute" (SUBMIT)
--- end of FORM
--- FORM report. Uses POST to URL "Job/fail"
Button: "Execute" (SUBMIT)
--- end of FORM
```

I'm trying to click the "Execute" button under either Pass or Fail

Answer (score 0):

You'll need this: https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Use web inspector or a proxy to check what exactly is being sent.